# Display modal-backdrop only for a nested modal

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using AngularJS and have many Bootstrap modals in a single html. 
Since I need to interact with the surrounding area while accessing the modals, I've set:

```
.modal-backdrop {
    display: none;
}
```

However, now I need to add a nested modal which must have a backdrop.
How do I do this?

Comment: You can specify CSS like Angular 4 does. You need just add any attribute to your tag, e.g. `<div class="modal" ngsss/>`. Then you need to specify it in CSS `.modal[ngsss]`

Comment: Ok, but how do I set the backdrop for this specific nested modal?

Comment: would be something like .modal-backdrop[ngsss] { display: all } ?

Comment: It's not a property of `display`. You can specify `block`

Comment: I tried setting display:block... didn't work. I think its because the original rule  is still active.

Comment: Try to solve this with bootstrap's help. It may use some special things to find needed modal. However, nested modals don't work according to their specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ensure no backdrop on the first modal opened (at the same time)...
Checking for it on each `data-toggle='modal'` button click.

```
$(document).on("click","[data-toggle='modal']",function(){
  $(".modal-backdrop").eq(0).css({"display":"none"});

  // if more than 1 modal openned.
  if($(".modal-backdrop").length>1){

    // move backdrop up (in z)
    var ZindexBackdrop = parseInt($(".modal-backdrop").eq(0).css("z-index"))+20;
    console.log("Backdrop z-index: "+ZindexBackdrop);
    $(".modal-backdrop").eq(1).css({"z-index":ZindexBackdrop});

    // move modal up (in z)
    var ZindexModal = parseInt($(".modal").eq(0).css("z-index"))+20;
    console.log("Modal z-index: "+ZindexModal);
    $(".modal").eq(1).css({"z-index":ZindexModal});
  }
});
```

To do change the second modal / backdrop `z-index` above the first...
Your second modal must **NOT** really be "nested" in the first one.
Because `z-index` of a child can not be changed if a parent has one defined.

But to have the desired nesting effect, place the second modal **trigger button only** in the first modal.

```js
$(document).on("click","[data-toggle='modal']",function(){
  $(".modal-backdrop").eq(0).css({"display":"none"});

  // if more than 1 modal openned.
  if($(".modal-backdrop").length>1){

    // move backdrop up (in z)
    var ZindexBackdrop = parseInt($(".modal-backdrop").eq(0).css("z-index"))+20;
    console.log("Backdrop z-index: "+ZindexBackdrop);
    $(".modal-backdrop").eq(1).css({"z-index":ZindexBackdrop});

    // move modal up (in z)
    var ZindexModal = parseInt($(".modal").eq(0).css("z-index"))+20;
    console.log("Modal z-index: "+ZindexModal);
    $(".modal").eq(1).css({"z-index":ZindexModal});
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1 Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        There is no modal back-drop...<br>
        Open this second one!<br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal</button>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- Nested modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 2 Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is the second modal.<br>
        <b>And there is a back-drop.
          </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Nested modal -->
```

Comment: it's not closing right (at least in the snippet), if you click outside the nested modal

Comment: This is just an example about how to hide the first backdrop. Don't ask for fully working nested modals. You didn't even post your HTML. I won't edit.

Comment: Sure, I'm not asking, thank you anyway.
I guess that using `backdrop:static` on the nested modal would fix the problem, if someone would try to use the code you posted.

Comment: Louys, I just noticed something: the backdrop is being applied in the parent modal (the backdrop is not covering the parent modal). Would you know how to make it to be applied in the nested modal, making it cover the parent modal, please?

Comment: I edited about that... And this also fixes the "click ouside" closing behavior.