# Multiple bootstrap modals overlaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, bootstrap-modal, backbone-events

I have a form modal in a Backbone.js app that successfully hides on submission of the form. But when I log out, create a new user and trigger the modal again, it will now be two modals overlaid on top of each other. Then three... etc. If I want to hide the modal again, I have to click outside of the modal twice, or three times or however many times the trigger modal + log out + sign up + trigger modal process has happened.

I have tried looking for similar problems but have not found the solution. I don't know if something is being cached or if I'm simply removing the modal the wrong way.

Has anyone seen this kind of problem before? Any thoughts?

[There are two divs each of .modal-backdrop and .modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN0oj.png)

Thanks in advance.

This is the function that responds to the click.

```
onSaveAccountBtnClick: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setTimeout(function () {
          this.event_bus.trigger('LoginMain.openSignUpView', this.event_bus);
}.bind(this), 500);
```

The openSignUpView event triggers:

```
    onSignUpBtnClick: function(e) {
        new SignUpView({
            event_bus: this.event_bus ? this.event_bus : this
        }).render();
    }
```

Here is the success callback:

```
success: _.bind(function(session) {
                  // Set the session and go to the homepage
                  utils.setUserSession(session);
                  this.onModalHidden();
                  this.event_bus.trigger('LayoutView.unblock');
                  utils.removeLoginStyle();
                  utils.removeSignUpModal();
                  this.event_bus.trigger('Router.navigate', 'home', { trigger: true });
                }, this)
```

On success three functions are called

```
    onModalHidden: function(e) {
        if (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        this.$el.modal('hide');
        this.remove();
    }
```

and

```
    removeLoginStyle: function(){
        $('body').removeClass('login');
    }
```

and

```
    removeSignUpModal: function(){
        $('body').removeClass('modal-dialog');
        $('body').removeClass('sign-up-dialog');
    }
```

This is the modal sign-up.ejs

```
<div class="modal-dialog sign-up-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="glyphicon logo-modal icon-logo-outline-black"></div>
        <%if(session){%>
          <p class="modal-title-text">Let’s save your account for later use!</p>
        <%}else{%>
          <p class="modal-title-text">Let’s get you set up to look for high schools.</p>
        <%}%>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" >
        <strong>Oh snap!</strong> <span>An unknown error has occurred.</span>
    </div>
    <form class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
              <%if(!session){%>
                <p>What's your first name?</p>
                <input name="first_name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
              <%}%>
            <span class="help-block hidden">First Name can't be blank.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%if(session){%>
              <p>Change your Username</p>
              <input name="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<%=session.username%>">
            <%}else{%>
              <p>Create a Username</p>
              <input name="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <%}%>
            <span class="help-block hidden">Invalid Username.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Create a secret password.</p>
            <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <span class="help-block hidden">Password must be at least 6 chars.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="confirm_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            <span class="help-block hidden">Both passwords must match.</span>
        </div>
        </br>
        <p class="privacy">By clicking <%= session ? '"Save Account"' : '"Sign Up"'%> you agree that you have read and understood our <a class="goPrivacy">Privacy Policy</a></p>
        <%if(session){%>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save-account">SAVE ACCOUNT</button>
        <%}else{%>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary sign-up">SIGN UP</button>
        <%}%>
    </form>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <!--<a class="modal-footer-text" href="#">Already Member of SchoolSearch?</a></br>-->
        <!--<a class="create-account open-login">LOG IN</a>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

The initialize function

```
        initialize: function (options) {
        _.extend(this, options);
        this.model = this.model || new UserModel();
        this.model.set('organization_id', 100);
    }
```

Here is the afterRender function

```
        afterRender: function() {
        this.$el.modal('show');

        this.$error         = this.$('.alert-danger');
        this.$error_msg     = this.$error.find('span');
    }
```

And onModalShown

```
        onModalShown: function(e) {
        this.bindValidation();
    }
```

Comment: For that I need to see your code, how you display modal?
One possible case may be you're hiding modal on close but recreating a div(modal) when you want to display content. That's why your modal gets displayed again and again. Please check that.

Comment: I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjquery%5d%20answers%3a0%2b%20closed%3ano%20duplicate%3ano%20isaccepted%3ano) a couple days ago. I don't think it is a duplicate of yours, but it may be relevant to you. **Post your code**.

Comment: @Nitesh It seems you are correct on the recreation of the div(modal). What would be a way to fix this? I added code for context. Thanks!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Your link goes to a list of questions not a specific one. Is that link correct?

Comment: Could we see the `render` and `initialize` methods of your view? I suspect that the way you have written the render is duplicating content, ie adding new modal html multiple times to the page, but I could tell for sure if I saw the render. One way to avoid this: don't create a new view at each button click, just find a way to redisplay the modal with the same view (probably by just triggering `render` once more on the existing view).

Comment: @dlugo06: sorry!! Wrong cut n' paste ;) [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45249471/display-modal-backdrop-only-for-a-nested-modal/45250053#45250053)

Comment: @arbuthnott I added the afterRender and initialize functions above. I only sort of understand what you mean. I am totally new to front-end frameworks. How would I am creating a new view vs rendering?